# Why does startAfter in this firebase query isn't working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the next function using firebase in an JavaScript app. The query works fine the first time because lastDoc isn't defined so it gets the first 7 documents in the database, but the next time when there's a lastDoc, the query keeps returning the same first 7 docs. The lastDoc variable is updated and indeed gets the value of the next doc.

```js
const getPosts = async ({loadMore=false, lastDoc}: { loadMore: boolean, lastDoc?: any}) => {
    let col = collection(db, "posts");

    let q = query(col,
            orderBy("updateDate", "desc"),
            limit(7),
            startAfter(lastDoc));
    
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

    let newLastDoc = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.size-1];

    let posts = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        if(doc.data().inactive == false || !doc.data().inactive) return {...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
        else return null
    }).filter((post: any) => post !== null);

    return {posts, lastDoc: newLastDoc};
}
```

The first time the lastDoc is undefined, and returns docs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7.
The second time the lastDoc is:

```js
{
  _firestore: {...},
  _userDataWriter: {...},
  _key: {...},
  _document: {..., data: {DATA_FROM_THE_7th_DOC}},
  _converter: null
}
```

, and keeps returning docs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7

Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the legacy version of the JavaScript SDK, [`startAfter`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Query#startafter) was defined as:

```js
Query<T>#startAfter(...fieldValues: any[]): Query<T>;
Query<T>#startAfter(snapshot: DocumentSnapshot<any>): Query<T>;
```

In the modern JavaScript SDK, [`startAfter`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#startafter) is defined as:

```js
function startAfter(...fieldValues: unknown[]): QueryStartAtConstraint;
function startAfter(snapshot: DocumentSnapshot<any>): QueryStartAtConstraint;
```

This means that your code should be functioning as expected. HOWEVER, based on the [provided project code](https://github.com/CampusMarket/posts-api/blob/754921b196646fabaef07b12db695b0538918c08/src/routes/getPosts.ts) from the comments, this is for an Express API, not client-side JavaScript.

Your query isn't working as expected because `lastDoc` is not a true `DocumentSnapshot` object at all and is instead a JavaScript version of it churned out by `res.json()`. Instead of returning a mangled `DocumentSnapshot` object to the client, we should instead just send back the data we need to pass as the `startAfter` arguments. In our case, we'll send back just the `updateDate` parameter inside of `lastDocData`:

```js
return {
    posts,
    lastDocData: {
        updateDate: newLastDoc.get("updateDate")
    }
};
```

Then when the data comes back to the API, we'll pass it to `startAfter`:

```js
startAfter(lastDocData.updateDate)) // Assumes lastDocData is { updateDate: number }
```

---

While reviewing [`methods/getPosts.ts`](https://github.com/CampusMarket/posts-api/blob/754921b196646fabaef07b12db695b0538918c08/src/methods/getPosts.ts), I noticed lines similar to the following:

```js
let q = !loadMore
    ? category && category !== "TODOS"
        ? query(
            col,
            where("school", "==", school?.code),
            where("category", "==", category),
            where("inactive", "==", false),
            orderBy("updateDate", "desc"),
            limit(7)
        )
        : query(
            col,
            where("school", "==", school.code),
            where("inactive", "==", false),
            orderBy("updateDate", "desc"),
            limit(7)
        )
    : category && category === "TODOS" // note: condition does not match above
        ? query(
            col,
            where("school", "==", school?.code),
            where("inactive", "==", false),
            orderBy("updateDate", "desc"),
            limit(7),
            startAfter(lastDocData.updateDate))
        )
        : query(
            col,
            where("school", "==", school.code),
            where("category", "==", category),
            where("inactive", "==", false),
            orderBy("updateDate", "desc"),
            limit(7),
            startAfter(lastDocData.updateDate)
        );
```

Because `query` takes a variable number of arguments, you can use the spread operator (`...`) to optionally include some arguments. As a simplified example:

```
let includeC = false,
    result = [];

result.push(
  'a',
  'b',
  ...(includeC ? ['c'] : []),
  'd'
);

console.log(result); // => ['a', 'b', 'd']

includeC = true;
result = [];

result.push(
  'a',
  'b',
  ...(includeC ? ['c'] : []),
  'd'
);

console.log(result); // => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

This allows you to use the following query builder instead:

```
const q = query(
    colRef,
    ...(school?.code ? [where("school", "==", school.code)] : []), // include school code filter, only if provided
    ...(category && category !== "TODOS" ? [where("category", "==", category)] : []), // include category filter, only if provided and not "TODOS"
    where("inactive", "==", false),
    orderBy("updateDate", "desc"),
    limit(7),
    ...(lastDocData?.updateDate ? [startAfter(lastDocData.updateDate)] : []) // Assumes lastDocData is a { updateDate: number }
);
```

---

Bringing this all together gives:

```
// methods/getPosts.ts
import { School } from '../../types';
import app from '../../firebaseconfig';
import { getFirestore, collection, query, where, getDocs, limit, orderBy, startAfter } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';

const db = getFirestore(app);

const getPosts = ({category, school, dataSavingMode=false, lastDocData}: {category: string, school: School, dataSavingMode: boolean, lastDocData?: { updateDate: number }}) => {
    const colRef = collection(db, dataSavingMode ? "dataSavingPosts" "posts");

    const q = query(
        colRef,
        ...(school?.code ? [where("school", "==", school.code)] : []),
        ...(category && category !== "TODOS" ? [where("category", "==", category)] : []),
        where("inactive", "==", false),
        orderBy("updateDate", "desc"),
        limit(7),
        ...(lastDocData?.updateDate ? [startAfter(lastDocData.updateDate)] : []),
    );

    const querySnap = await getDocs(q),
        postDocsArr = querySnap.docs,
        lastDoc = postDocsArr[postDocsArr.length - 1],
        noMorePosts = postDocsArr.length < 7;
        
    const postDataArr = postDocsArr
        .filter(docSnap => !docSnap.get("inactive")) // shouldn't be needed with above filter
        .map(docSnap => ({ ...docSnap.data(), id: docSnap.id }));

    return {
        posts: postDataArr,
        noMorePosts,
        lastDocData: { updateDate: lastDoc.get("updateDate") }
    }
}

export default getPosts;
```

```
// routes/getPosts.ts
import express from 'express';
import { School } from '../../types';

const router = express.Router();

// Methods
import getPosts from '../methods/getPosts';

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const reqBody: {
        school: School,
        category: string,
        lastDocData?: any,
        dataSavingMode?: boolean
    } = req.body;

    const {posts, lastDocData, noMorePosts} = await getPosts({
        category: reqBody.category,
        school: reqBody.school,
        dataSavingMode: reqBody.dataSavingMode,
        lastDocData: reqBody.lastDocData
    });

    res.json({posts, lastDocData, noMorePosts});
})

export default router;
```

Comment: So i delete the orderBy filter as well? like this query(col, limit(7), startAfter(lastDoc.get("updateDate")); or should i keep it?

Comment: @GonzálezLópezDavid No, you still need the `orderBy` declaration, as it defines what the values represent in the `startAfter` filter. e.g. If you had the following `orderBy` calls: `orderBy('date'), orderBy('count'), orderBy('name')`, the `startAfter` call would have to be `startAfter(someDate, someNumber, someName)`.

Comment: It throws an error saying that "lastDoc.get is not a function"

Comment: The type of the new last doc says that is QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>, is there something wrong with this line of code? let newLastDoc = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.size-1];

Comment: @GonzálezLópezDavid My code expected that `lastDoc` was a `QueryDocumentSnapshot`, but your code also allows it to be `undefined` too. So maybe use `startAfter(lastDoc ? lastDoc.get("updateDate") : undefined)`

Comment: @samthecodingman The guide docs show that it's still possible to pass a `DocumentSnapshot`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query, which is also what I thought.

Comment: @samthecodingman I'm checking with the engineering team to see if this is an oversight in our reference docs and/or in our typings, and will report back here.

Comment: @samthecodingman it recognizes the .get as a function when it is assigned to newLastDoc but it doesn't recognize it before when passed to it as a param. Here is the full code of the server i'm applying this to if it is of any help https://github.com/CampusMarket/posts-api/blob/main/src/methods/getPosts.ts

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Looks like the reference documents are out of date as the JS SDK source still has [the right typings](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/31055413ea16e4548f741736ece11b3927291fdb/packages/firestore/src/lite-api/query.ts#L331-L361). OPs code would be working as intended if they passed in an instance of `DocumentSnapshot`, but instead were passing in a plain JavaScript object.

Comment: @GonzálezLópezDavid Take a crack at the changes to the answer and let us know how you get on.

Comment: It still doesn't work, it keeps returning the same first 7 docs

Comment: Can you add `console.log(JSON.stringify(reqBody))` just before the `getPosts` call? I suspect that the data isn't properly being handed back to the API.

Comment: The first time it loads the posts it logs **`{"school":{"city":"Saltillo","name":"Instituto Tecnológico de Saltillo","code":"SAL-TECNM"},"category":"TODOS"}`** then in the second request loading more posts it logs **`{"school":{"city":"Saltillo","name":"Instituto Tecnológico de Saltillo","code":"SAL-TECNM"},"category":"TODOS","loadMore":true,"lastDoc":{"updateDate":{"seconds":1669417757,"nanoseconds":122000000}}}`**

Comment: @GonzálezLópezDavid In the code I posted it handles `lastDocData`, not `lastDoc`.

Comment: I only changed the name back to lastDoc in the code because in the client side it handles it with that name

Comment: @GonzálezLópezDavid Righto, then it's probably because your `updateDate` is a Firestore `Timestamp` object whereas I had assumed it was a plain number (unix timestamp). You'll need to feed the timestamp as a `Timestamp` object - using `{seconds: number, nanoseconds: number}` doesn't work. Use `startAfter(new Timestamp(lastDoc.updateDate.seconds, lastDoc.updateDate.nanoseconds))`. This is why you should never use the `any` type as it breaks things.

Comment: I've been struggling with that bug for days, and that fixed everything, i'll make sure to never use the any type again, thank you so much for your patience and comments